# Send POST method by HttpURLConnection to an unknown devices

Tags: java, post, http-post, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400

I have a device that should be configured.
It has a `WEB Interface`, by `IP x.x.x.x` , I can connect to the device by `IP` in the `Browser` and do them, Now the customer want a software to do this.
The device core is a `customized Linux`.
I want to find the `Services` and `Parameters` that it send via web Interface.
So i opened the `web interface` and go to the `IP` and the part i wanted to change.
After change fields in the `web`, i clicked on the `Apply Button`.
I had also Downloaded `Fiddler` and Opened `Developer Tools` of `FireFox`.
In `Developer Tools` after i clicked on `Apply`, one `POST method` appears, Others are all `Get Method`.
Also after i clicked on `Apply Button`, the actual `URL` change from `x.x.x.x/services` to `x.x.x.x/apply.cgi`.
So it seems i can do them by the `x.x.x.x/apply.cgi` URL.
I Opened the `Developer Tools` and `POST method` request header is like :

```
Host: x.x.x.x
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0)    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://x.x.x.x/Services.asp
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDoxMjM0NQ==
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

In the `TextView` of Fiddler we have this :

```
submit_button=Services&action=ApplyTake&change_action=&submit_type=&commit=1&static_leases=13&openvpn_certtype=&dhcpd_usejffs=&dhcpd_usenvram=0
(It is alot, i just copy part of that )
enter code here
```

I think i could write a simple calling `HttpURLConnection` By this way, this is my code :

```
    public class PostHTTPSample {
   private String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";  
   String userCredentials = "root:xxxxxx";

    public void sendRequestPost() throws IOException { 
    try {
        String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((userCredentials).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  //Java 8
        String str = "http://x.x.x.x/apply.cgi";
        URL obj = new URL(str);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+"cm9vdDoxMjM0NQ=="); // I even tested encoded String that i has declared and define above
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "x.x.x.x");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

        String urlParameters = "The String Copied from Fiddler(Above) For test";
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + str);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PostHTTPSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    }
```

Ok, i make an instance from this class and run the method, it gives me `Response Code : 400` .
And the run Console of `Netbeans` :

```
    Feb 01, 2017 3:16:13 PM posthttpsample.PostHTTPSample main
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://x.x.x.x/apply.cgi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at posthttpsample.PostHTTPSample.sendRequestPost(PostHTTPSample.java:58)
    at posthttpsample.PostHTTPSample.main(PostHTTPSample.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://x.x.x.x/apply.cgi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at posthttpsample.PostHTTPSample.sendRequestPost(PostHTTPSample.java:52)
    ... 1 more
    enter code here
```

What i am doing wrong?
What should i do?
Any suggestion?

EDIT : I can use `GET` method of this URL, it gives me `200 OK response`.
But still can not use `POST` method.

Comment: I would check with wireshark, whats the difference between requests from java vs. browser. Also you removed credential root password but not base64.

Comment: I can do get with Basic cm9vdDoxMjM0NQ== ( it was in Developer tools )
How do you think about this?
Does my URL is correct? does it seems to be correct?

Comment: In GET method the response code is 200. 
It means it is OK.